# Emacs 24's python.el + ipython cannot complete module names

Tags: python, emacs, ipython, emacs24, python.el

I'm using Emacs 24.4.1 on OSX (installed with Homebrew), with the built in `python.el`, and Python 3 (also installed with Homebrew), along with IPython 2.3.0. I have this in my `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setq
 python-shell-interpreter "/usr/local/bin/ipython3"
 python-shell-prompt-regexp "In \\[[0-9]+\\]: "
 python-shell-prompt-output-regexp "Out\\[[0-9]+\\]: "
 python-shell-completion-setup-code
 "from IPython.core.completerlib import module_completion"
 python-shell-completion-module-string-code
 "';'.join(module_completion('''%s'''))\n"
 python-shell-completion-string-code
 "';'.join(get_ipython().Completer.all_completions('''%s'''))\n")
```

Everything works correctly when I invoke `M-x run-python`, except one thing: the `<tab>`-completion of module names doesn't work in the REPL (it says "No match" in the `*Messages*` buffer). I'm pretty sure it was working with Emacs 24.3, which I upgraded very recently, but I'm not 100% sure. Anyone has an idea what might cause this, or how I could try to debug it?

Comment: Why are you using Emacs 25? It's a not a stable version. The current stable version of emacs is 24.4.1.

Comment: @Jack That was the result of simply doing `$ brew reinstall emacs --HEAD --cocoa --srgb`.

Comment: Right, so it appears `--HEAD` is giving you a version of emacs that is not yet stable (the current dev branch). Is that what you actually want though?

Comment: I just assumed that `--HEAD` was the way to do it, since that's what you most commonly see everywhere. I guess that simply doing `$ brew reinstall emacs` (i.e. without any option) would revert to stable?

Comment: My understanding is you see that command everywhere because until Oct 20 when 24.4.1 was offically released that was how you got it...but now that 24.4.1 has been officially released it now gives you the next version they're working on (25.x). It seems like `$ brew reinstall emacs` will give you 24.4.1 now.

Comment: I am now running 24.4.1, but my problem is still there though.

Comment: You might like to try and remove most of your settings above, since Emacs-24.4 should support IPython pretty much out of the box.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, that solves my problem indeed, it's so simple. If you want to create an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to try and remove most of your settings above, since Emacs-24.4 should support IPython pretty much out of the box.